# Regarding elementary complex arithmetic in J.B. conway's proposition 3.10

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

[image]

In $(3.12)$ how is it possible to take $\beta $ inside since beta is real ? I think it should be $im(\alpha\omega-i\beta$ . Am I correct ? It seems easy but it gives headaches for two days . Could someone please explain this.

Comment: It may seems kinda stupid question but I stuck in this for days. Hopefully I'm not so dumb 

Comment: Yes, it's a mistake by Conway.

Comment: Oh @Daniel Fischer I should have asked here before but I thought I could figure it out on my own. Could you just add what is correct line that complete that argument.  So I can check it with what I have . Thanks

Comment: The correct equation is $\operatorname{Im} (\alpha \omega) = \beta$ or anything equivalent to it. That defines a perfectly fine straight line (which is a circle [minus the point $\infty$] in the sphere) if $\alpha \neq 0$.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer Thankyou for clarify it.